# Commutation relations for inverse d'Alembertian operator

Tags: general-relativity, operators, tensor-calculus, differentiation, commutator

Is there a commutation relation for the inverse d'Alembertian operator in general relativity? i.e. if we define $\Box = g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu$ and $\Box \Box^{-1}X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}=X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}$ then is there a way to get $[\nabla_\mu,\frac{1}{\Box}]X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}$ in terms of $[\nabla_\mu,\Box]X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}$?

It is possible to do the following:

$\Box [\nabla_\mu, \frac{1}{\Box}] X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}=\Box \nabla_\mu \frac{1}{\Box} X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}-\Box\frac{1}{\Box} \nabla_\mu  X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}\\
=\Box \nabla_\mu \frac{1}{\Box} X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}- \nabla_\mu  \Box\frac{1}{\Box}X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}\\
=[\Box ,\nabla_\mu ]\frac{1}{\Box} X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}$

If $\Box^{-1}\Box  X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...} =X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}$ was true then we could divide by $\Box$ from the left to reach
$\Box [\nabla_\mu, \frac{1}{\Box}] X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}=[\Box ,\nabla_\mu ]\frac{1}{\Box} X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}\\
\Box^{-1} \Box[\nabla_\mu, \frac{1}{\Box}] X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}=\frac{1}{\Box}[\Box ,\nabla_\mu ]\frac{1}{\Box} X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}\\
[\nabla_\mu, \frac{1}{\Box}] X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}=\frac{1}{\Box}[\Box ,\nabla_\mu ]\frac{1}{\Box} X_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...}$

as Prahar suggests, but I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Can you at least try to define $\Box^{-1}$ properly?

Comment: To elaborate on the previous comment: please note that wave operator is not invertible.

Comment: @Blazej $\square$ is an invertible operator

Comment: It is not. In fact it annihilates constants. It may or may not be invertible when restricted to some particular space of functions, but nothing like that was mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Blazej If $\square$ was not invertible, we wouldn't have free EM waves, Coulomb potential, gravitational waves, and everything else that needs the description of propagating massless fields. Look into any QFT book, for instance, sec 3.4 of Schwartz.

Comment: To the point about invertibility and the need for a proper definition, what is $\Box^{-1} 0$ for you?  Surely any constant is equally good. I’m not convinced the operator is defined let alone a commutator of it, *especially as a two-sided inverse.*

Answer (score 1):

For matrices
$$
[A , B^{-1} ] = - B^{-1} [ A , B ] B^{-1} 
$$
So extending to operators
$$
[\nabla_\mu , \Box^{-1} ] = -\Box^{-1} [ \nabla_\mu , \Box ] \Box^{-1}
$$